# How do I install a specific version of chromedriver on Debian 11?

Tags: debian, software-installation, drivers, directory, chrome

I need to install a version of Chromedriver for Google Chrome 83, which is the version of Chrome I need for the github script I'm trying to run (https://github.com/banyous/quora-scraper).

I've already downloaded Chromedriver 83 to my computer.
What command do I need to run to install it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To install chromedriver:

```
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip  -d /tmp
sudo mv -f /tmp/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```